# How do you reset the StringValidator?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

after the form has been sent I want the form to be cleared. So I set the .text = "";

but the stringvalidator is red because the fields are empty again. How do I make it so that the form is reset along with the Validators?

Answer (score 0):

To reset, you should use `.text=null;`